# Smooth map rotation in navigation kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, gps

I have problem with smooth map rotation. I use Sensor and onSensorChanged to get direction which side the user is looking at. Then I put it to math degrees (rage -180 : 180)

```
degres = Math.toDegrees(mOrientation.get(0).toDouble())
```

and then pass it to other function

```
if (gps != null) {
            if(degres!! !in lastDegres!!-10..lastDegres!!+10 && degres!!>0 || degres!! !in lastDegres!!-10 ..lastDegres!!+10 && degres!!<0 ){
                //here
                lastDegres = degres
            }
        }
```

if statement avoid shaking map when sensor get a little movement.

My problem is what I have type in this if statement to smoothly rotate map. I already trying something like this :

```
if (gps != null) {
            if(degres!! !in lastDegres!!-10..lastDegres!!+10 && degres!!>0 || degres!! !in lastDegres!!-10 ..lastDegres!!+10 && degres!!<0 ){
                var result = (lastDegres!!  - (degres!! )).toInt()

                    for (i in 0..result) {
                        setOrientation(((180 + lastDegres!! + i ).toFloat()))
                        update()
                    }
                lastDegres = degres
            }
        }
```

but it's work only in only right direction, any advices how to allow to rotate smoothly to left and right ?

// ANSWER
if u want use this next step is find closest site left or right to actually position

```
        if (gps != null) {
            realpos = degres!! * -1
            if (realpos < 0) realpos += 360
            dif = if (realpos > lastDegres!!) { realpos - lastDegres!! } else { (lastDegres!! - realpos) }

            if (dif > 10) {
                if(realpos > lastDegres!!){
                    for (i in 1..dif.toInt()*50000) {
                        orientation = (lastDegres!!.toFloat()+i/50000)
                        update()
                    }
                }else if (lastDegres!! > realpos) {
                    for (i in 1..dif.toInt()*50000){
                        orientation = (lastDegres!!.toFloat()-i/50000)
                        update()
                    }
                }
            lastDegres = realpos
        }
```

Comment: You're making your own navigation app? With what map data?

Comment: I using navigation SDK

Comment: Mapbox you mean?

Comment: PTV ..............